# LED matrix power and multiplexing

Tags: power-supply, multiplexer, esp32, shift-register, led-matrix

I am trying to build a 7 character LED matrix (so 5x7 x 7 LEDs). I need it to be controllable from an ESP32 with Arduino code. So far what I've learned is that I need shift registers in order to control the columns (or rows) without sacrificing to many IOs and I need to use multiplexing in order to be able to control the single LEDs. What I still can't figure out is how could the shift register work in series and how to manage the multiplexing and external powering of the LED. Also I've seen online projects using decade counters but I haven't figure out the advantage of using them rather than shift registers. Regarding power for the LEDs I figured I'd be safe around 5A to 6A at 5v but I can't figure out what kind of device I need (why should I choose a transformer over a power supply? For the latter, should I buy one specific for LEDs or not?).Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

The 5A to 6A guess is based on the fact that the display will need high power LEDs since it will be used in the open (must be real bright) and needs to be visible from about 20m. I only need to display 7char at the time, so I worked out I need 20mA(7rows5colums)7char=4.9A

Comment: What kind of display do you want to utilize? 5A to 6A at  5V is way too much for a regular small display.

Comment: The display will need high power LEDs since it will be used in the open (must be real bright) and needs to be visible from about 20m. I only need to display 7char at the time, so I worked out I need 20mA(7rows5colums)7char=4.9A

Comment: Well then add this info to your question. Also give us the datasheet of the display you intend to use.

Comment: Updated, also the "display" is just a matrix I am trying to diy build, so I don't have a data sheet. As I said in the question I am still trying to figure out how to properly manage power, the shift registers and multiplexing

Comment: have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Degt4HUzWXY and https://www.instructables.com/Practical-Guide-to-LEDs-4-Matrix-Multiplexing/

Comment: The specs don't make much sense. If you use 20mA per LED for all LEDs at once, it would be 3.5A, but then it also means no multiplexing, and 20mA per LED can be quite little. But if you do multiplex, it means that max 1 full row of 7x5 or 1 full letter of 7x5 is light up at once, so 0.7A only if 20mA per LED. So you can boost LED current but keep it on for fraction of time.

Comment: @FrancescoAntonioMiccoli Are you saying you need (7) 5x7 characters in a daylight visible display? There is a great deal that goes into making a display used in daylight. And it is NOT only about the emitter power per pixel/segment. It's about the display background, about the use of polarizing filters that can nearly eliminate solar reflection by extinguishing light that transits the filter twice through reflection from the background, and lots of other important details. When you've grappled with these, then and only then can the LED power itself be more fully addressed and worked out.

Comment: @FrancescoAntonioMiccoli The very best book on this topic is from HP, many years ago: *"Optoelectronics: Fiber-Optics Applications Manual,"* 2nd edition. Nothing better exists, so far as I've seen since it came out nearly 40 years ago.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. Regarding multiplexing yes, that would greatly reduce my power consumption, thanks for pointing that out. Still I wouldn’t know how to properly choose a device to power the “display”, in that regard any help is appreciated. Filtering the sunlight is also something I’ll definitely think through, I kind of took inspiration from outdoor advertising signs and they don’t seem to have filters, that’s why I didn’t think about it in the first place. Also thank you for the resources, I will definitely take a look at them.

Comment: @FrancescoAntonioMiccoli I worked on the modules (from Siemens-OSRAM) that are (were) used in making those outdoor advertising signs. The modules I worked on look like [this](http://www.infinitefactors.org/misc/images/p1000046_640x480.jpg). (Those are my initials signed on the displays there.) These are RGB LED modules and an incredible number of them are used to make up a full sized display. Each one of those modules represent about 100 W of power dissipation. An entire display has a HUGE power system behind it. Monstrous! You've no idea, I suspect.

Comment: @jonk thank for the comment. I am not trying to make a big display like you mentioned. I only need 7 characters (245LEDs in total). I was asking help designing a power system for such an application